# ProgressDialog no se muestra. Android Studio y JAVA

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio, progressdialog

tengo el siguiente problema al querer mostrar un ProgressDialog en mi App.

Tengo un Login, lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar un botón y cuando empiece y acabe la consulta a la base de datos en SQL Server (buscando al usuario ingresado) aparezca un ProgressDialog. Y como mencioné anteriormente, éste se quite de la pantalla hasta que la consulta sea satisfactoria.

Ya he intentado pero nunca me aparece, no sé que estoy haciendo mal.
El código es el siguiente.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtUsuario, edtPassword;
Button btnIngresar, btnProbar;
String usr, pass;

private ProgressDialog pd; //Se crea el progress

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("OBTENIENDO DATOS...");//Mensaje personalizado en el Progress----------

    edtUsuario = findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);
    edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    btnIngresar = findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);


    edtUsuario.requestFocus();
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            usr = edtUsuario.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);//Se obtiene el usuario eliminando espacios y convirtiendo el texto a minusculas
            pass = edtPassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);//Se obtiene la pass eliminando espacios y convirtiendo el texto a minusculas

            if (!usr.isEmpty() || !pass.isEmpty() || !usr.equals("") || !pass.equals("")) {


                pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);//El progress no se quite al presionar la pantalla
                pd.show();//Mostrar el ProgressDialog!


                Connection con = conexion();
                if (con != null) {
                    String f = fechaActual();//Almacenamos el retorno del metodo en la variable f
                    if (f != null) {
                        //Creando Intent para inciar la nueva actividad
                        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Inicio.class); //Creando Intent de la Interfaz Principal
                        i.putExtra("usuario", usr);//Se agrega el usuario al intent para poder ocuparlo en la Actividad Inicio
                        i.putExtra("password", pass);//Se agrega la password al intent para poder ocuparlo en la Actividad Inicio
                        i.putExtra("fecha", f);//Se agrega la fecha al intent

                        pd.dismiss();//Quitar el ProgressDialog de la pantalla!

                        startActivity(i);//Abriendo la Interfaz Pricipal con los datos ingresados
                        finish();//Terminar actividad login y quedarse con la de Inicio

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "¡Sesión iniciada correctamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"----> "+f, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al obtener fecha. Intente de nuevo...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error. Intente de nuevo...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Faltan datos por ingresar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

public Connection conexion() {
    Connection conexion = null;

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();//Driver de Conexion a la BD
        //Ruta de Acceso con el usuario y contraseña ingresadoo.s
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://urlbasededatos;databaseName=prueba;user=" + usr + ";password=" + pass + ";");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Mostar mensajes de error en el login
    }
    return conexion;
}
```

}

No estoy muy seguro si tiene algo que ver la conexion a la base de datos. O si conocen una mejor y más eficiente forma de hacer lo que quiero. Es bienvenida :)
Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: `ProgressDialog` es un elemento obsoleto en Android desde la API 26 [como podrás leer en la nota](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog). El motivo es que Progress Dialog bloquea la UI, impidiendo al usuario interactuar con la aplicación. Siendo que a día de hoy Android ha publicado hasta la API 32, hablamos de que intentas usar un elemento declarado obsoleto hace ya mucho tiempo. Considera usar [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) en su lugar.

Comment: Ya intente con el ProgressDialog y me sigue haciendo lo mismo. No me aparece.

Comment: ¿Por qué no intentas con `ProgressBar`? No te recomiendo que programes tu app usando elementos obsoletos.

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo una consulta direactamente en el MainThread. Para lograr esto de activar un progress debes hacerlo a través de tareas asyncronas o coroutines.

Como resultado de tu soución la UI se bloquea hasta completar la consulta y luego no termina de mostrar tu progress dialog.